Using two PID controllers to ensure motor encoder count error is zero
I'm attempting to build a differential drive robot using the arduino 33 BLE Sense. For programming, I'm using a combination of both arduino and MBED OS.
I'm using the following encoders attached to the motors: https://www.pololu.com/product/3081. Due to constraints, I only have access to channel A.
I've been attempting to use PID controllers to ensure that each motor has a close to zero error in encoder count difference. The ultimate aim of this is to make sure my robot moves in a straight line and doesn't eventually veer off. The following code was my attempt at creating a function which moves the robot a set number of counts whilst checking that it hasn't veered off:
 void RobotBody::move(int distance, float speed, int forw_backw){ // 0 = forwards, 1 = backwards 
    
    int old_steps_A = motor_list[0]->getSteps(); // hardcode for now 
       
    int old_steps_B = motor_list[1]->getSteps();

    motor_list[0]->setSteps(0);

    motor_list[1]->setSteps(0); 
    
    float distance_in_steps = round(((distance/(M_PI*4.8))*330)); // hardcode for now
    
    motor_list[0]->setMotorDirection((forw_backw == BACKWARDS) ? 1 : 0);
    
    motor_list[1]->setMotorDirection((forw_backw == BACKWARDS) ? 1 : 0);
    
    motor_list[0]->changeVelocity(speed); // left 
    
    motor_list[1]->changeVelocity(speed); // right 
    
    while(((motor_list[0]->getSteps() + motor_list[1]->getSteps())/2) < distance_in_steps){ // 219+219/2 = 219
    
      PID_list[0]->getSetpointPointer() = motor_list[0]->getSteps(); 
      PID_list[1]->getSetpointPointer() = motor_list[1]->getSteps(); 
      
      current_error = (motor_list[0]->getSteps() - motor_list[1]->getSteps());
      
      PID_list[0]->getInputPointer() = motor_list[0]->getSteps(); 
      PID_list[1]->getInputPointer() = motor_list[1]->getSteps(); 
      
      PID_list[0]->Compute(); 
      PID_list[1]->Compute();
      
      
      if(current_error > 0){
          Serial.println("Red wheel further ahead!");
          analogWrite(10, );
      } else if(current_error < 0){
          Serial.println("Yellow wheel further ahead!");
      }
    
      
      
    }
    
    motor_list[0]->changeVelocity(0); // left 
    
    motor_list[1]->changeVelocity(0); // right 
    
    // reset steps + add/subtract new: 
    motor_list[0]->setSteps((forw_backw == FORWARDS) ? (old_steps_A + (int)distance_in_steps) : (old_steps_A - (int)distance_in_steps));

    motor_list[1]->setSteps((forw_backw == FORWARDS) ? (old_steps_B + (int)distance_in_steps) : (old_steps_B - (int)distance_in_steps));
    
    // update world x and y: 
    
    
    
    return; 
};

I don't conceptually understand how you would correct the left and right wheel PWM outputs by using the PID outputs in order to ensure that the error remains close to zero. What would the setpoints for each of the motors be for each individual case?
My general thoughts regarding a solution were adjusting the PWM of each wheel depending on whether the error was positive or negative - some other attempted solutions included adding or subtracting the output of the PID controller from the PWM of the motors, but the robot ultimately veered off course anyway.
I've been stuck on this problem for a while and would greatly appreciate any suggestions or help.
